# Digital Person fingerprint image retrieving

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, image, fingerprint

I am using the following code to save the finger print scanned through Digital Persona's device.

```
Dim cls As New ClsDataAccess
Dim con = New SqlConnection(cls.SqlConnectiontring)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim str As New MemoryStream
Enroller.Template.Serialize(str)
Dim serializedTemplate As Byte() = str.ToArray()
'cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@fn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)).Value = "Joe"
'sql.DbType
Dim param(0) As SqlParameter
'Dim t As Integer = Join(serializedTemplate, ",")
param(0) = New SqlParameter("@biometricData", serializedTemplate)

'Public OnlineConnectionString As String = "Data Source = 203.234.5.678; Database = mydb; User CndID = username; Password = xxxxxx;"

'Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into tbltestbio (biovalue) Values (@biometricData)", con)
'cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

Dim pictureParameter As SqlClient.SqlParameter = New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Picture", SqlDbType.Binary)
pictureParameter.Value = serializedTemplate
cmd.Parameters.Add(pictureParameter)
```

The problem is that when I try to retrieve the image using memory stream like an ordinary image, it won't load. Any other image using my Object Browser is being displayed by this code. What am I doing wrong? Below is the code for image retrieval.

```
Sub ImageLoadFun(ByVal barrImg() As Byte)
    Try
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(barrImg)
        Dim returnImage As Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        PictureBox1.Image = returnImage.Image
        EmployeeDrawPicture(img)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you get "template" from sensor and not "image".

Template is a list of [minutiae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minutiae) and other info.

You need to check in your FingerPrint API if there's method to get image.
Be careful, usually image, from fingerprint sensor, is not in RGB format but in greyscale.